# I dont know what to do with Ubuntu ISO file

Tags: iso

So trying to find the iso for Ubuntu to put on my flash drive but when I download I get a prompt to open with winrar and when I do extract it’s just a bunch of random folders and I have no idea where the ISO is can someone help point me in the right directions since I have no idea what I’m doing.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't open that iso file. You have to burn it into a flash drive in order to make it bootable as a Ubuntu live disk, therefore you can install Ubuntu in your machine.
Since you're in Windows you can use one of these tools to make the pendrive bootable.

- [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) (**Recomanded**)
- [Etcher](https://etcher.io/)
- [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)